# jQuery UI positioning

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to position a jQuery keyboard that by default is set to 'Null' (is displayed directly below input elements).

```
$.keyboard.defaultOptions = {

        // *** choose layout & positioning ***
        layout       : 'qwerty',
        customLayout : null,

        position     : {
            of : null, // optional - null (attach to input/textarea) or a jQuery object (attach elsewhere)
            my : 'center top',
            at : 'center top',
            at2: 'center bottom' // used when "usePreview" is false (centers the keyboard at the bottom of the input/textarea)
        }
```

What I want to do however is attach the keyboard to a div with an id of 'foo'.

What would the code above look like with this change in place?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the above code is not enough. Please provide the link to your jQuery plugin, maybe we can come up with something.

Comment: Hi @KalleH.Väravas, thanks for your help. Much appreciated. The link to the full project is: https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to make the keyboard static, so when you visit the page you'll see it. Now popups, no tricks, just keyboard? However, where will the content you type go?

Comment: Hi @KalleH.Väravas, almost right. I'm wanting the behavior of the keyboard to remain as is, with the exception of the keyboards position. The default behavior is for the keyboard to appear under the active input when clicked, I want the keyboard to appear at the bottom of the page when an input is clicked. I want the keyboard to only appear on-click, the way it is by default.

Comment: The problem with that is, that I think this keyboard needs alot of source-work. Since it adds the input in the keyboard container and overlays the original input. If it works like this, then the things typed, will be added once the keyboard is closed. So basically you not only have to cut out the overlay-input from the keyboard container, but also change how the script works and make it, so it adds the characters to the original input live.